# How do I compile a list from one line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to create a list from one line in a file, but I cannot find a way on how to do it, does anybody have any tips on how to do it?

```
"text.txt file"
22 21 20
```

And this is my latest attempt to do it, but the list is not split into three elements, but instead is one whole string.

```
f = open("file.txt")

line = f.readline()
line = line.replace(" ", ", ")
list1 = [line]
print(list1)

Output:
['22, 21, 20']
```

Comment: Just do `list1 = f.readline().split()`. Replacing commas with spaces doesn't magically cause a string to be interpreted as a list with multiple items.

Comment: And if you want to convert everything to integers, just do `list1 = [*map(int, f.readline().split())]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split()` to split the string into a list of strings.  If you want to turn those strings into `int`s, call `int` on each one.

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    list1 = f.readline().split()

print(list1)              # ['22', '21', '20']
print([int(n) for n in list1])  # [22, 21, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
with open("tasks.txt", 'r') as data:
    data=[int(each_int) for ele  in data.readlines() for each_int in ele.split() ]
```

print(data)